# Binding a DataSet's DataTable to a DataGridView

Tags: c++, winforms, binding, datagridview

There's lots of info on binding freestanding DataTable objects to DataGridViews, but is it possible to bind a DataTable which is embedded in a DataSet to a DataGridView? How would I go about doing so?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a program which has multiple DataTable objects being used which need to be saved and loaded from single files, which is where the DataSet object comes into play. I then need to display data from these various DataTables in different parts of the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

DataTables that are inside of DataSets work just like other DataTables.
You can bind to one like any other table.

```
grid.DataSource = someDataSet.Tables["SomeName"]
```

Comment: thanks. just syntax - I was trying to use parentheses instead of square brackets